# How do the Sanctuary spell and the Sentinel feat interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, attack

The description of the Sanctuary spell (PHB p 272) says:

> You ward a creature within range against attack. Until the spell ends, any creature who targets the warded creature with an attack or harmful spell must first make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the creature must choose a new target or lose the attack or spell.

The description of the Sentinel feat (PHB p 169) says:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a creature other than you...you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

If a character with the Sentinel feat is also warded by Sanctuary, and an attacker fails the Wisdom saving throw and attacks a different target within 5 feet of the character, will this still trigger the melee attack reaction?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the attack being caused by *Sanctuary* will not prevent it from triggering Sentinel. You've already quoted the important rule:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a creature other than you (and that target doesn't have this feat) you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

There's no conditions placed on this. If a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a creature other than you, you get your reaction to hit them. It doesn't matter what kind of attack, it doesn't matter what caused the attack. **Any** attack triggers Sentinel.

Comment: I feel someone should mention the final clause of Sanctuary, just in case the QA (question asker?) isn't aware that this will result in Sanctuary ending.
*"If the warded creature makes an attack (even a reaction attack as per Sentinel) or casts a spell that effects an enemy creature, this spell ends"*

Comment: I think it's worth explicitly calling out the "**can**" in that quote, because it means you can choose not to invoke your Sentinel reaction in order to preserve Sanctuary.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely.

The trigger for Sentinel is "When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a creature other than you". An attack is rolling a d20 to overcome AC - if someone does that then you can thump them.

The reason for making the attack is irrelevant; its the fact of it that matters. Sentinel does not care if the attack was made as a result of Sanctuary or because of what that guy said about our Sharon.